Configure Jenkins in different GKE clusters
Im trying to configure jenkins in 2 different k8s cloud.
My setup is like this:

jenkins master at gke cluster named "devops-cluster" in project1.
A second gke cluster named "qa-tests" in project2.

I did configure seccusfully master jenkins in "devops-cluster" and agents are created in there and everything is good.
I also have DNS for the "devops-cluster" network loadbalancer so I can connect jenkins by URL, and its working fine.
I configured a second cloud for gke cluster "qa-tests". it seems I can create agents there but there is no connection between jnlp container to the jenkins master.
This is where I need the help, I tried:

WebSocket - looked like it worked but it didnt.
jenkins tunnel - didnt work too

Im doing something wrong i guess. Maybe i missed something with the kubenetes plugin.
